# Store java arrays to file for read and write

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am fairly new to StackOverflow so I'm sorry if this question is not written correctly.

I'm currently learning java and I'm looking for a way to store a set of arrays as a file so that changes to the array will persist between different instances of the program. I would need to read an write any changes to the best times list to a file.

I have done some research into storing arrays but most of what I've read seems to only store a simple array of strings, integers, ect. These arrays are a little bit more complex so I'm not sure how to do it.
I don't expect anyone to write all of my code for me but I could use some help on knowing where to start.

This is the sample data that would need to be stored. These are best times for a java game.

Are there methods to store this kind of data in a file of some sort?

```
public class BestTimes 
    {
        BestTimes[] beginner = new BestTimes[10];
        BestTimes[] intermediate = new BestTimes[10];
        BestTimes[] expert = new BestTimes[10];

        public BestTimes() {
        beginner[0] = new BestTimes(1, "John", 10.5);
        beginner[1] = new BestTimes(2, "James", 20.3);
        beginner[2] = new BestTimes(3, "Jill", 30);
        beginner[3] = new BestTimes(4, "Bill", 35);
        beginner[4] = new BestTimes(5, "Kevin", 40);
        beginner[5] = new BestTimes(6, "Nate", 55);
        beginner[6] = new BestTimes(7, "Bob", 75);
        beginner[7] = new BestTimes(8, "Dan", 85);
        beginner[8] = new BestTimes(9, "Amy", 93);
        beginner[9] = new BestTimes(10, "Jane", 100);

        intermediate[0] = new BestTimes(1, "John", 110.5);
        intermediate[1] = new BestTimes(2, "James", 120.3);
        intermediate[2] = new BestTimes(3, "Jill", 130);
        intermediate[3] = new BestTimes(4, "Bill", 135);
        intermediate[4] = new BestTimes(5, "Kevin", 140);
        intermediate[5] = new BestTimes(6, "Nate", 155);
        intermediate[6] = new BestTimes(7, "Bob", 175);
        intermediate[7] = new BestTimes(8, "Dan", 185);
        intermediate[8] = new BestTimes(9, "Amy", 193);
        intermediate[9] = new BestTimes(10, "Jane", 200);

        expert[0] = new BestTimes(1, "John", 210.5);
        expert[1] = new BestTimes(2, "James", 220.3);
        expert[2] = new BestTimes(3, "Jill", 230);
        expert[3] = new BestTimes(4, "Bill", 235);
        expert[4] = new BestTimes(5, "Kevin", 240);
        expert[5] = new BestTimes(6, "Nate", 255);
        expert[6] = new BestTimes(7, "Bob", 275);
        expert[7] = new BestTimes(8, "Dan", 285);
        expert[8] = new BestTimes(9, "Amy", 293);
        expert[9] = new BestTimes(10, "Jane", 300);
        }

    public int ranking;
    public String playerName;
    public double time;

    public BestTimes(int r, String p, double t) 
    {
        ranking = r;
        playerName = p;
        time = t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mostly I have done reading and research on how to do it. I haven't written much code yet. I figured out how to put simple text into a file, but this is much different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to store an object (datastructure), you need to *serialize* it: convert it to an stream of bytes, characters, whatever.

There exist multiple ways to serialize an object ranging from JSON over XML to the [*object serializer/deserializer*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#4176).

For instance (as specified in the webpage):

First you must add `implements Serializable` at the end of the class definition, so:

```
public class BestTimes implements Serializable {
```

Then you can serialize using:

```
try(FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    ObjectOutput s = new ObjectOutputStream(f)) {
    s.writeObject(beginner);
    s.writeObject(intermediate);
    s.writeObject(expert);
}
```

And later read it as:

```
BestTimes[] beginner, intermediate, expert;
try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(in)) {
    beginner = (BestTimes[]) s.readObject();
    intermediate = (BestTimes[]) s.readObject();
    expert = (BestTimes[]) s.readObject();
}
```

The easy thing about the object serializer is that you don't have to define a format on your own. That's the task of the Java virtual machine, and furthermore it can encode **all** kinds of objects whereas JSON for instance can't handle datastructures that contain loops (example: graphs), XML can't handle loops as well and CSV is only well suited for table content.

A disadvantage however is that the datastructures are encoded **binary**: they cannot be read easily. Although in this case that might be an advantage since some users tend to alter the file to increase their highscores ;).

Comment: Make sure you close the streams.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: done, many thanks for constructive comments.

Comment: +1 for this, I much prefer it to JSON. But I would suggest you either use `try-with-resources` or at least a `try..finally`. The current code is one massive resource leak waiting to happen...

Comment: @BoristheSpider: better?

Comment: I tried to implement this solution but I am getting a NotSerializableException on the line `s.writeObject(beginner);`

Comment: @kb4000: forgot to tell, you simply must add `implements Serializable` to the class definition...

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'm still testing my application real quick and then I'll mark the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @CommuSoft The code compiles and runs with no errors but my output file is completely empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the size of the file. It is not unreasonable you can't see any characters... And evidently, you first need to populate the array before serializing.

Comment: @CommuSoft 0 bytes. Doesn't my code from above populate the array?

Comment: @kb4000 the `close` and `flush` statements were very confused. I have edited them. Try now. Also maybe print `Arrays.toString` to the console before serialization to see what you have in the array. The file should never be empty as it should at least have a "magic number" as a header.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I figured out the problem. I had implemented the close part wrong so it was clearing out my file. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this would be to serialize the arrays as JSON and store their JSON representation.

There is no reason to come up with your own solution to serializing arrays, as it is already a solved problem! The easier the better in my opinion.

Comment: @ByteHamster I don't think anything could be easier than using a JSON library as that makes this a one-liner.

Comment: the only problem with JSON is that when reference-cycles occur, problems start to appear.

Comment: Why JSON. Why not just _serialize_ them?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Its a fair point, but I assumed for a beginner something that is somewhat human readable is easier to understand than raw serialization

Comment: @CommuSoft That is not going to happen with the array examples he provided.

Comment: Swings and roundabouts - external libraries are also quite complex for a beginner. Especially if the beginner isn't using Maven...

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have not used Java in a couple of years, but it does not have built in JSON serialization still?

Comment: @thatidiotguy: well what if at some point, the OP changes his/her mind an want to encode a graph or anything. The advantage of using the Java serializer is that you don't need to think about how to encode...

Answer (score 2):

As others have said using some JSON-Library to read/write your data to files is a valid option.

If you want a more pure Java approach you can model your data in classes implementing the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface and read/write them using Java's [ObjectOutput-](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Comment: I originally wanted to put my data in classes as you've mentioned but my instructor wants us to use arrays. :(

Comment: @kb4000: an `Array` is an object as well. You can simply put it in the `ObjectOutputStream` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would either use a database, or export your content as CSV (comma separated values) file. You could introduce a 4th attribute the stands for the `type` of your data (beginner, expert etc).

```
1, John, 110, beginner
2, Mark, 90, professional
...
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I think that would simplify things a lot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in csv file too,

Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.csvreader.CsvWriter;

public class CsvWriterAppendExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String outputFile = "users.csv";

    // before we open the file check to see if it already exists
    boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();

    try {
        // use FileWriter constructor that specifies open for appending
        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), ',');

        // if the file didn't already exist then we need to write out the header line
        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
            csvOutput.write("id");
            csvOutput.write("name");
            csvOutput.endRecord();
        }
        // else assume that the file already has the correct header line

        // write out a few records
        csvOutput.write("1");
        csvOutput.write("Bruce");
        csvOutput.endRecord();

        csvOutput.write("2");
        csvOutput.write("John");
        csvOutput.endRecord();

        csvOutput.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
}
```

Output Format

```
id,name
1,Bruce
2,John
```

Check http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I ended up going with serializing this file especially since I don't want players to be able to edit the high scores, but CSV could be very useful in the future.