# How to get array.length after it has been deserialized

Tags: java

So, I'm working on a project that automates everything from character sheets to dice rolls for a table top RPG I like to play. I'm trying to store character data (character name, 2 arrays of stats, and 2 arrays of those stat values) that can be accessed at the start of executing the app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570967/store-java-arrays-to-file-for-read-and-write) has been very helpful so far.

However, I'd also like to display the name and stats so the user can confirm that this is the character data they want to use. And I'm having trouble displaying the data in a readable format. Here's my code (you'll find the problem I'm having toward the bottom, although if you see anything else that could be optimized along the way, I would appreciate any feedback :-)":

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class fengShuiFiles implements Serializable {//start class

    private FileOutputStream outFile;
    private ObjectOutput objectWriter;
    private FileInputStream inFile;
    private ObjectInputStream objectReader;

    public void WriteFile(String fileNameIn, String[] sArray1, String[] sArray2,
            String[] sArray3, String[] sArray4) {
        try {
            outFile = new FileOutputStream(fileNameIn + ".txt", true);
            objectWriter = new ObjectOutputStream(outFile);
            objectWriter.writeObject(sArray1);
            objectWriter.writeObject(sArray2);
            objectWriter.writeObject(sArray3);
            objectWriter.writeObject(sArray4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I/O occurred during a write operation\nFor more",
                    "information see console output.",
                    "Read File", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // End try/catch
    } // End Open

    //not sure if I'll need this. Keeping it for now just in case
    //public void writeRecords(String textRecords)
    //{
    //  outFile.close();
    //  pw.println(textRecords);
    //} // End WriteRecords
    public void ReadFile(String fileNamein) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fengShuiFiles[] sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4;
        try {
            inFile = new FileInputStream(fileNamein + ".txt");
            objectReader = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);
            sArray1 = (fengShuiFiles[]) objectReader.readObject();
            sArray2 = (fengShuiFiles[]) objectReader.readObject();
            sArray3 = (fengShuiFiles[]) objectReader.readObject();
            sArray4 = (fengShuiFiles[]) objectReader.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I/O error occurred opening a",
                    "file\nFor more information see console output.",
                    "Read File", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // End try/catch

        for (int x = 0; x < sArray1.length; x++) {

        }
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        try {
            outFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // End closeFile
}//end class
```

So, that `sArray1.length` in the for statement toward the bottom? It's coming up with an error message saying that sArray1 may not have been initialized. And I'm having trouble figuring out why, and how I can get that length so I can print out the arrays in a readable manner. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize local variables. If an exception occurs, it's possible that some or all of the arrays aren't initialized and the compiler won't allow that.

The easiest way to get rid of the error is to initialize the arrays to `null`, but your program has a logic problem. You're catching the exceptions and continuing, even though there's no way your program can work correctly after that. You should instead throw the exceptions out of the `readFile()` method and then most likely exit the program. You could also continue as if the file didn't exist, but at least show a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to initialize variables in java. You do this in your try block, but if an exception occurs, the array will not have been initialized.

You can move the for loop to the try block:

```
public void ReadFile(String fileNamein) throws FileNotFoundException {
    fengShuiFiles[] sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4;
    try {
        ...
        for(int x = 0; x < sArray1.length; x++) {

        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        ...
    } // End try/catch
}
```

Or use a default value to initialize the array in the catch block:

```
public void ReadFile(String fileNamein) throws FileNotFoundException {
    fengShuiFiles[] sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4;
    try {
        ...

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        ...
        sArray1 = new fengShuiFiles[0]; // Some default value.
    } // End try/catch

    for(int x = 0; x < sArray1.length; x++) {

    }
}
```

---

Something that might be more convenient though, is to return the read arrays, and do something with them in the calling method.

For instance:

```
public Optional<fengShuiFiles[][]> ReadFile(String fileNamein) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {
        fengShuiFiles[] sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4;
        // read the file
        return Optional.of(new fenShuiFiles[][]{ sArray1, sArray2, sArray3, sArray4 });
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        ...
        return OPtional.empty();
    }
}
```

Then in some other method:

```
Optional<fengShuiFiles[][]> ret = ReadFile(...);

if(ret.isPresent()) {
    for(fengShuiFiles[] arr : ret.get()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // Print here
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that WOULD be a lot more convenient. I was thinking I might have to create two separate methods for displaying and utilizing. Thanks a bunch!